# Update if data available not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to PHP and Mysql . I have a table ( stock ), I'm trying to insert data into it, If same data is already there then the same has to be updated according to user input.

```
    $sql=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE medName = $medName");

if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) 
{
    $sqlUpdate="update stock set qunty= qunty +'$qunty'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sqlUpdate);
} else {
    $sqlInsert="insert into stock set medName= '$medName', qunty= '$qunty',phyLoc= '$phyLoc',printPrice= '$printPrice',menufName= '$menufName'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sqlInsert);
}
```

But  above code is only storing the value if it is not already there, It is NOT updating data if it is already stored. Someone help me please.

Thank You all.

Comment: did you check if `$qunty` has the right/expected value? (do a `var_dump($qunty);` to verify)

Comment: Yes! $qunty has expected value

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. You have some issues in your query regarding quotes. Also you need where condition  on update

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE medName = '$medName'");

$sqlQuery="insert into stock set medName= '$medName', qunty= '$qunty',phyLoc= '$phyLoc',printPrice= '$printPrice',menufName= '$menufName'";   
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)  {
    $sqlQuery="update stock set qunty= qunty + $qunty WHERE medName = '$medName'";
}

mysqli_query($conn,$sqlQuery);
```